# Only half of array gets raised to power

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, binary

I wanted to create binary to decimal calculator.
When i tried to console log both of arrays (binary is array of 0's and 1's, binarypos is array of numbers that are powers of 2.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sMC4.png)

Then i created simpler version, made in console so chance of making a mistake lowered to zero. But the bug appears again!

```
const x = Array(8).fill(1);

const xpos = Array(8).fill(0);

for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    xpos[x.length - 1 - i] = Number(x[i]);
    xpos[i] = Math.pow(xpos[i] * 2, [i]);
  }
console.log(xpos) // [1, 1, 1, 1, 16, 32, 64, 128]
```

I want it to look like this

```
console.log(xpos) // [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't it be simpler to just do something like this?

```
const x = Array(8).fill(1);
const xpos = [];

for (let i = 0, j=1; i < x.length ; i++, j*=2 ) {
  xpos[i] = j;
}
```

Or for what your screenshot suggests that you're trying to accomplish: converting a string of binary digits (`0` or `1`) into its decimal representation, just:

```
function binaryToDecimal( digits ) {
  const isValid = /^[01]+$/.test(digits);
  if (!isValid) {
    throw new TypeError("bindDigits must be a string containing only '0' and '1'.");
  }
 
  let value = 0;
  let p = 1;
  for ( const d of digits.split('').map( d => +d ).reverse() ) {
    value += d * p;
    p *= 2;
  }

  return value;
}
```

Comment: Yes! Thank You. I am a beginner!

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```js
const x = Array(8).fill(1);

const xpos = x.map((n,i) => Math.pow(2,i));

console.log( xpos );
```